# Bash Script works locally but not from server

Tags: bash

I have a script which runs fine when executed locally on a mac.

```
# Ask to make system changes
read -p "Would You Like to make system changes? (Finder, etc...) ? (y/n)?" CONT
if [ "$CONT" == "y" ]; then

# Keep-alive: update existing `sudo` time stamp until `mac.sh` has finished
echo "Keep this mac alive while ding this task..."
while true; do sudo -n true; sleep 60; kill -0 "$$" || exit; done  2>/dev/null &
# Show Date on menubar
echo "Showing Date on menubar..."
defaults write com.apple.menuextra.clock.plist DateFormat "EEE dd MMM h:mm:ss a"
killall "SystemUIServer";

else
  echo "Done makng system changes"
fi
```

But when I try remotely like this:

```
curl -s https://192.168.63.23/mac.sh --insecure | sh
```

I get this error:

```
sh: line 93: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
sh: line 93: `else'
```

Comment: Try executing it from `bash` and not `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't executing anything remotely; you are just copying the script from a remote server to execute locally. One problem is that your script uses `bash` extensions like `read -p`, but you are executing it with `sh` (which, even if it is a link to `bash`, executes in POSIX mode). Use `bash` explicitly:

```
curl -s --insecure https:/192.168.63.23/mac.sh  | bash
```

As for the syntax error, run your code through `shellcheck.net`. You haven't shown enough of the actual code to locate the problem.